# How to select option from dropdown with Selenium when this element is not defined in HTML structure

Tags: php, selenium, automation, webdriver

I need to submit entered address into Google maps.
After entered text into Search field dropdown with addresses is shown. This dropdown is not defined in html structure and I can not operate with it via xpath or css selectors.

[image]

I have tried to do it via WebDriverKeys() but it was not helped:

```
    public function enterTextIntoFieldMap(WebDriverBy $element, string $text)
    {
        try{
            $this->client->findElement($element)->clear()->sendKeys($text);
            $this->client->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::PAGE_DOWN);
            $this->client->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
            sleep(2);
        }catch (WebDriverException $exception){
            Assert::fail("Impossible to enter text into field");
        }
    }
```

Please, advise, how to select any option from dropdown in this situation.

Comment: It's probably driven by AJAX, so there _will_ be HTML (it cannot be shown on screen otherwise) but it's not a conventional `<select>` and the options won't be there when the page loads. I don't know much about selenium but I'd guess it contains a way to wait for an async request to finish and then search the DOM again.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML